# IP6tables blocks INPUT? can't connect with youtube API

Tags: iptables, ipv6

I thought to have a simple ipv6 firewall, but it turned out to be hell.
Somehow I really can't connect with any ipv6 from my machine unless I set INPUT Policy to ACCEPT. Below my current ip6tables

ip6tables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere           tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If I try to connect with any ipv6 adres it doesn't work?

```
telnet gdata.youtube.com 80
Trying 2a00:1450:4013:c00::76...
```

OR

```
telnet gdata.youtube.com 443
Trying 2a00:1450:4013:c00::76...
```

When I set:

```
ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

It works.. but then.. well then everything is open? what is going on?
Help?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the critical "stateful" rule:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You are also missing a rule to accept ICMPv6. Without ICMPv6, IPv6 simply does not function.

```
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

For performance reasons, this should be among the earliest rules in your chain.

Comment: Noope that did not work.. i flushed the input rules and first added your rule:
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Oops, I forgot something. See the updated answer.

Comment: i updated my post in the top, but no result... i did both the things you mention, you can see the ip6tables -L  in the top